# How to define the function out side the Library?

Tags: c++, qt

we have some dynamic plugin-dll, which is generated through separate protect, and  use while the software is start. Plugin-dll code is use some of header file from main project. while compiling plugin code, If main project header file contain some function, and  definition outside the class, at that time I am getting error like unresolved external symbol.

This error are expected because of plugin code does not find the definition of (main project) function.

Note: plugin must be compile before compilation of main project.

In two situation plug in code is compile. 
1) If main project header file has pure virtual function then it is work 
   perfectly (plug code is compile fine).
2) If I will write the function definition inside the class.

I tried inline function but it is did not work.

```
---------------------
*** Main Project ***
---------------------
 ->This project generate .exe file 

mainProject.h
-------------
class MainProjectHeder{

   virtual void foo() = 0;    // this function is work 
   void foo1();              // this function giving me error like unresolved external symbol  
   void foo2{                // this work
     print("hello");
   };
};

void MainProjectHeder::foo1(){
     print("function not working");
}  


ExperimentFactoryInterface.h 
----------------------------
#include <MainProjectHeder.h>

class ExperimentFactoryInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ExperimentFactoryInterface() {}
    virtual MainProjectHeder* CreateExperiment(const QVariant& = QVariant()) = 0;
};



----------------------
  *** Pulgin code  ***  
----------------------
->This Project is generate DLL file

Experiment.h 
-------------

#include <mainProject.h>
class Experiment : public MainProjectHeder{

      virtual void foo();  
};

void Experiment:foo(){
    print("work fine");
}  


Factory.h
----------
#include "cyclicvoltammetry.h"
#include <ExperimentFactoryInterface.h>

class Factory : public ExperimentFactoryInterface {
public:
    MainProjectHeder* CreateExperiment(const QVariant& = QVariant());
};


MainProjectHeder* Factory::CreateExperiment(const QVariant&) {
    return new Experiment;
}
```

while compiling code of plugIn; how can I inform to compiler like definition of function `void foo1();` is write out side the project or in another project?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do.  Is `foo1` defined in your main project, but needs to be called by a plugin?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  Yes, ```foo1``` is define in main project. It is call by plugin function while run time.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a (incoming search term!) callback.

Answer (score 0):

A member function of a class is a function that has its definition or its prototype within the class definition like any other variable. It operates on any object of the class of which it is a member, and has access to all the members of a class for that object.